# ChartJS and Ajax calls

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, chart.js

I would like to make charts using ChartJS and PHP ( Silex Framework )

This is my ajax call

```
$.ajax({ url: 'stats',
   data: {method: 'dossierRepartitionType'},
   type: 'post',
   datatype: 'json',
   success: function(output) {
               dataDossierRepartitionType=output;
             },
   error: function () {
                 alert("Oops there is an error.");
  }});
```

This is my PHP function which i managed to call

```
public function dossier(){
$stmt = "SELECT count(*) FROM dossier GROUP BY typedossier";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($stmt);
$rows=$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
return ?????
```

}

And here is my chart :

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
ctx.width = 400;
ctx.height = 400;
data = {
  datasets: [{
  data: [dataDossierRepartitionType, 20],
  backgroundColor: [
  'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
  'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
  ],
  borderColor: [
  'white',
  'white',
  ],
  borderWidth: 1
  }],

  // These labels appear in the legend and in the tooltips when hovering        different arcs
  labels: [
    'Red',
    'Blue',
  ]
  };
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'doughnut',
data: data,
options: {
legend: {
labels: {
    fontColor: "white",
    fontSize: 18
}
},
maintainAspectRatio: false,
responsive: false
}
});
```

Route.php

```
$app->post('/stats', function () use ($app) {
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['method']) && !empty($_POST['method'])) {
  $method = $_POST['method'];
  switch($method) {
    case 'dossierRepartitionType' :
     $dossiers=$app['dao.dossier']->dossierRepartitionType();
     break;
    }
  }
  return new ResponseSilex("$dossiers");
 });
```

So my AJAX call the route and then get the result of the function into `$dossiers` which is ouput in the Reponse, am i doing it right ?

How can i return an array with all the datas value for each count ?
I struggle to catch error and to find a proper way to bind MYSQL count value to my chart

Thank you

Comment: To generate the required JSON output you could use [PHPChartJS](https://github.com/halfpastfouram/PHPChartJS)

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is that you should format your data in your model, then return JSON to the front end via `json_encode`. After that, you would parse the json in your ajax returns and then pass the appropriate data to the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can send `JSON` data from php

**Try this:**

**Php:**

```
public function dossier(){
    $stmt = "SELECT count(*) FROM dossier GROUP BY typedossier";
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($stmt);
    $rows=$stmt->execute();
    $rows = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    exit(json_encode(array('counts' => $rows)));
}
```

After ajax successfully complete you need to initialize chart plugin inside success callback like below:

**Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({ url: 'stats',
   data: {method: 'dossierRepartitionType'},
   type: 'post',
   datatype: 'json',
   success: function(output) {
      if (output.counts) {
        dataDossierRepartitionType=output.counts.join();
        alert(dataDossierRepartitionType)
        initCharts(dataDossierRepartitionType);
      }
   },
   error: function () {
                 alert("Oops there is an error.");
  }});
```

Finally wrap chart initialization code inside callback function

**Chart:**

```
function initCharts(dataDossierRepartitionType){
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    ctx.width = 400;
    ctx.height = 400;
    data = {
      datasets: [{
      data: [dataDossierRepartitionType, 20],
      backgroundColor: [
      'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
      ],
      borderColor: [
      'white',
      'white',
      ],
      borderWidth: 1
      }],

      // These labels appear in the legend and in the tooltips when hovering        different arcs
      labels: [
        'Red',
        'Blue',
      ]
      };
    var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'doughnut',
    data: data,
    options: {
    legend: {
    labels: {
        fontColor: "white",
        fontSize: 18
    }
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: false
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: Also,  let me know what is the output of `alert(dataDossierRepartitionType)` ? so that we can make sure ajax is returning proper response

Comment: Does the above solution works for you? If so then please mark this answer as useful so that it helps others too :) Otherwise let me know what is the result of `alert(dataDossierRepartitionType)`

Comment: Hello, sorry for the long answer, i was not on my main computer, i didn't get any output from the code you gave me, neither the error nor the success, i have add a route to my ajax call ( I use Silex )

Answer (score 0):

it's very easy, you need to modify your php code like this:

```
    public function dossier(){
$stmt = "SELECT count(*) as total FROM dossier";
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($stmt);
$rows=$stmt->execute();
$number_of_rows = $rows->fetchColumn(); 

return json_encode(["total" => $number_of_rows]);
```

In your ajax petition you are specifying a "json" return so in your script php need's return a json.

```
$.ajax({ url: 'stats',
   data: {method: 'dossierRepartitionType'},
   type: 'post',
   datatype: 'json',
   success: function(output) {
               dataDossierRepartitionType=output.total;
             },
   error: function () {
                 alert("Oops there is an error.");
  }});
```

You should to receive a json from php with this structure

```
{total: rows_total}
```

so in your ajax response you'll receive that answer and you can get the data like this:

```
dataDossierRepartitionType=output.total;
```

Sorry for my english, hope can help you